# Login to Angular ASP.NET CORE app using Postman

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, postman

I would like to login my app using postman and receive a token when login to make other api call with the token. I have tried {locahost}/connect/token but I get a 405 error. How can I login to my
app using postman thank you for your help.

Here is how I generated the app

1. I open visual studio 2019.
2. I chose "Create a new project"
3. Chose ASP.NET Core With Angular
   [image: Select Core With Angular]
4. Click next
5. Give it a name
6. Save it where you would like
7. In dropDown "Authentication Type" select "Invidual Accounts"

Once the app is created the login and register work perfectly but I want to the these api calls in Postman.

Here is the startup that visual studio generated for me.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<erp_colombiaDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<erp_colombiaDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, erp_colombiaDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I Have seen this answer [Default settings for AddApiAuthorization (Scaffolded Angular + IdentityServer4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613282/default-settings-for-addapiauthorization-scaffolded-angular-identityserver4) but I don't understand where he got the values from to fill the postman form "GET NEW ACCESS TOKEN"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default settings for AddApiAuthorization (Scaffolded Angular + IdentityServer4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613282/default-settings-for-addapiauthorization-scaffolded-angular-identityserver4)

Comment: 1) The code you shared doesn't show the `/connect/token` endpoint. Please provide the code of the relevant controller  
2) Also, which method did you use to call the endpoint?

Comment: @CGundlach connect/token enpoint is what I found on google but I dont see that endpoint in my code.

Comment: @JCH I am not sure wich type of authorization he choses. in the type dropdown waht type of authorization must I choses and What values most I fill in? That is more my problem.

Comment: @JCH I belive that I found the authentication type it is OAuth 2.0 I have tried to fill in the fields but I get Authentication failed I am unsure wish filed I have to fill and where I can get the information from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this in response to comments above.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613282/default-settings-for-addapiauthorization-scaffolded-angular-identityserver4), the answer from user [@Lasanga Guruge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9524580/lasanga-guruge) points out the default values for a basic scaffolded application. So these settings should work for you in Postman

> 1. Grantype of Authorization Code
> 2. ClientId will be corresponding to the application name. That can be changed in appsettings.json (Clients) and api-authorization.constants.ts (ApplicationName)
> 3. By default a client secret would not be applied to the client
> 4. Also pkce is enabled.
> 5. No default credentials
> 6. Additional scope named {ProjectName}API will be added

I created a basic ASP.Net Angular project and got it working with these values

- Grant Type - Authorization Code (With PKCE)
- Callback URL - https://localhost:{port}/authentication/login-callback
- Auth URL - https://localhost:{port}/connect/authorize
- Token URL - https://localhost:{port}/connect/token
- ClientId - {ClientId}
- Scope - {ClientId}API openid profile

[image]

To get your client ID look in appsettings.json for the IdentityServer section
In mine below, 'Project2" is my clientID. It should be whatever you named the project.

```json
"IdentityServer": {
  "Clients": {
    "Project2": {
      "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
    }
  }
}
```

### Update

To make an authorized API call with the token, you need to ensure it is set in the Authorization header of the request.

- Authorizaion = "Bearer {token}"

You should be able to set this by setting the 'Add authorization data to' field to 'Request Headers' in Postmans Authorization form.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you verry much now I understand better just one more question. Once I  have clicked on the Orange button "Get New Access Token" I have a green checkmark and I can see TokenName and its value. However when I make a call to {{base_url}}/api/clients I still get a 401. Why is that? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach You need to make sure the token is being used in the Authorization header of the request. I have updated the answer to include some details

Comment: Thank you Thank you! It works now. You are the best.